Movie with wrist watches that brought people back to life
I remember seeing a movie when I was a kid about high tech wrist watches that when wore, if the user would get himself killed, it would revive him. 
Other details:
- the guy got the watches from a friend who died;
- after each use the watch became useless;
- there were about 6-7 watches in total;
- the guy had a red car and at some points meets a chick;
If you could help me find it I would appreciated, I've been looking for it for a while now.
